# Restrictions for the naming of a SQL Server login?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on a legacy app that uses SQL Server as backend.

the application creates SQL Server logins too, in the code I found this check:

1) (Sql server) login name must not be null

2) it must not be made of a single char

3) it must not start with a digit (like '1test' is not an allowed name)

I didn't find corresponding documentation. May be these were restrictions of older releases? I support 2008R2 only at present.

Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189751.aspx

Comment: thanks, so login_name (in case of sql authentication) should be identifiers, so: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms175874.aspx come into place, about starting with a digit i quote from my last link "An identifier that starts with a number sign denotes a temporary table or procedure", may be this was the reasonò Anyway a login "1test" works fine

Comment: Using double quotes creates a delimited identifier, which doesn't have to obey the rules for identifiers, and must always be delimited when referenced. You can also use square brackets as delimiters.

Comment: @user193655 - re "number sign", the section you're reading defines "number sign" as `#`, not a digit, so it's not a preclusion on starting an identifier with a digit.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes tou are right, anyway my code says ecplicitly that the first char should not be in ['A' .. 'Z', 'a' .. 'z', '_', '\', '-', '.']

Answer (score 1):

Probably the developer that originally coded the application tried to stick to he naming convention for identifiers (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms175874.aspx) in a non 100% matching way.

This is just an hipothesis, when working on legacy code written by others too often it is needed to ask yourself "why did he do this?" and mostly "why didn't he write a short comment?"